# turnjs add form input to redirect page number

Tags: jquery, ajax, turnjs, pdf.js

I use turnjs to present our catalog , with the " magazine" model.
I would add an input form that redirects to the page number submitted .
Someone there already use a method ?
And if someone has already included pdf files? 
Thank's

Comment: Why not use the method provided by turnjs?  http://www.turnjs.com/docs/Method:_page

Answer (score 0):

I did with eventlistener

```
// listener to input value to go pagenumber
    function listenPage(){
        var p = document.getElementById("inputPageNumber");
        p.addEventListener("input", function() {
            var result = p.value;
            $('.magazine').turn("page", result);  
        }, false); 
    }
listenPage();
```